# Create directory inside today created (datetime) directory

Tags: python

I m new in python and also in stackoverflow even if I sometimes I read it for various issue...

These days I m approaching to python3 cause I would like to improve a simple procedure: everyday I need to download data from an ubuntu system to win 10 and create the relative path but this already happens and works fine.

I just want to add a function in this program (made from other people) and create a folder inside the folder created and named with the date of the day (so everyday this folder has a different name!).

```py
    import paramiko
    import stat
    import os
    import pandas as pd
    #from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
    from tqdm import tqdm
    import logging
    from logging_config import getJupyterHandler
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, handlers=[getJupyterHandler()])
    logging.getLogger('paramiko.transport').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    logging.getLogger('paramiko.transport.sftp').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    import datetime
    import utils

    root = '/...path'
    date = None
    overwrite_existing = False

    if date is None: 
    date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")
    logging.info("Checking data for today")
    else:
    logging.warning("Manual date is set")
    sftp = utils.getPandoraSFTP(ip='...')
    dates = sftp.listdir(root)
    if date not in dates:
    logging.error("No folder found")
    else:
    logging.info("Folder found")
    files, numberOfFiles = utils.getFileListToCopy(sftp, f"{root}/{date}", f"C:\\data\\to_upload\\ 
       {date}", f"C:\\data\\to_brighter\\{date}", True)
    logging.info("Download tags")
    tags = {k:v for k,v in files.items() if 'tag/' in k}
    if len(tags)>0:
        for remote, local in tags.items():
            if os.path.exists(local) == False or overwrite_existing:
                sftp.get(remote, local)
        logging.info("Create summary table")
        folder = os.path.dirname(list(tags.values())[0])
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'Time', 'type' ,'Function', 'Leveling', 'Weather', 
    'Illumination', 'visibility', 'Road Type', 'sky', 'other', 'Issue description', 'driver', 
    'tester'])
        for file in os.listdir(folder):
            if file.lower().endswith('csv'):
                try:
                    df = df.append(pd.read_csv(f"{folder}\\{file}", header=None, 
    names=df.columns))
                except Exception as e:
                    logging.error(f"Unable to process tag: {file} due to {e}")
        df['Location'] = ''
        filename = folder.split('\\')[-2]
        summary_path = f'...'
        df[['Time', 'Function', 'Road Type', 'Illumination', 'Weather', 'Location', 'Issue 
    description']].to_excel(summary_path, index=False, header=False)
        logging.info("Table created on ")
    else:
        logging.warning(f"No tags found")
    pbar = tqdm(files.items())
    for remote, local in pbar:
        pbar.set_postfix_str(os.path.basename(remote))
        if os.path.exists(local) == False or overwrite_existing:
            sftp.get(remote, local)
           
    #making new folder

    folder_n = "name of folder..."

    os.chdir ("C:\\data\\to_upload\\{date}") #choose directory   
    os.mkdir (folder_n)
```

How you can see in these lasts strings (#making new folder) I simply added a mkdir function for create the folder inside the folder {date}. Of course the error says that it does not find that path!
Could someone help me and suggest a way on how identify that folder?

Thanks

Comment: Correct the indentation of the codeblock. There's no indentation in `if-else` block.

Comment: I don't see how it does anything. The code you posted almost entirely resides in an unclosed string (`root`). And what's up with that path? `/...path`? Do you mean `..\path`?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
    os.chdir("C:\\data\\to_upload\\{date}")
```

but you wanted

```
    os.chdir(f"C:\\data\\to_upload\\{date}")
```

That is, you want an f-string to interpolate the `date` variable
so its value will become part of the string.

---

You'd be better off phrasing it as a raw r-string

```
    os.chdir(rf"C:\data\to_upload\{date}")
```

rather than doubling the `\` backwhacks.
Better still, just use regular `/` slashes:

```
    os.chdir(f"C:/data/to_upload/{date}")
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much, it works!!

So I missed that "f"! I was sure paths must be wrote just inside quotation but I will study in deep this aspect.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).